# How to use Default Silverlight 4 Context Menu AND custom context menu?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

This is what I would like:

I want to keep the Silverlight default menu options and build up my own global rightclick context menu. I added the menu to my mainpage .xaml and made my custom menu ([you can see the live version here](http://www.pokerdiy.com/poker-chip-calculator.aspx)) - this works fine (it currently only has "Resize to fullscreen").

This then suppresses the default Silverlight context menu with "Silverlight" and the install option, which is not cool. I want to show them both on one menu:

Possible Solution 1) Find out if there is a way inheriting default menu and extending (I doubt it)

Possible Solution 2) Suppress default and write custom links to emulate it.

So... is option 1 possible? If not, creating the install link is easy in code - but how do I get the Silverlight info? This is very useful for helping the user enable the data store/version debugging etc. Googling this was almost impossible with all the noise - hopefully someone can tell me how to load it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct there is no way to inherit the existing menu.

You can implement the install menu item yourself by using `Application.Install`.

You cannot open the Silverlight Config dialog, however, I would suggest that is no loss.  The dialog is not specific to your application and if the user wants to configure Silverlight they can still invoke from their Programs menu.

Comment: Thanks - I'll replicate the install menu.